# How do I find an element that matches a condition, but has no descendants that match the condition with xpath?

Tags: xpath

I would like to find the most specific match(es) for a particular condition.  For example, given the following HTML:

```
<div id="grandpa">    
  <div id="first_parent">
    <div id="first_child">
      <font>My</font>
      <br>
      <font>dog</font>
      <br>
      <font>spot</font>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="second_parent">
    <div id="second_child">
      <font>My</font>
      <br>
      <font>dog</font>
      <br>
      <font>spot</font>
    </div>
  </div>  
</div>
```

I would like an xpath that finds elements with the text "My dog spot", and gets me a nodeset with the divs 'first_child' and 'second_child' but does not get me 'first_parent' or 'second_parent' or 'grandpa'.  The id's in this snippet are for illustration, as is the actual structure of the snippet.  The important thing to understand is that the string might appear more than one time on the page, but I only want the most specific elements that contain them, not parent elements.  I realize that I'll get the child elements (the fonts and brs), but I only want to get them as result of getting 'first_child' and 'second_child'.  I don't want to get them as their own part of the result set.

I've tried:

```
$x( "./descendant::*[ starts-with(normalize-space(string()), 'My dog spot') and not(starts-with(normalize-space(string(./descendant::*)), 'My dog spot'))]" )
```

But it gets the html element as well as 'first_child' and 'second_child', when run with the Firefox 15 console (the platform I'm working with).

Comment: So, you want your result set to be `<div id="first_child"/>, <div="second_child"/>` without the child nodes? I don't think this is possible in XPath since it usually returns nodes of your XML. All non-leaf nodes still contain their children. However, usually the language that you call XPath with allows you to drop the children if required.

Comment: I realize that the nodes I get back will contain their children, that's fine.  I don't want to get them on their own in the result set.  The result set should be of length two.

I've modified the query to reflect this.

Comment: Hmmm, when I run your XPath on http://www.freeformatter.com/xpath-tester.html against your input (after changing `<br>` into `<br/>`) it returns exactly two elements.

Comment: If you run it in Firefox 15, and leave the brs as I had them, you'll get 3.  I'll update the question to be more precise.